# Calculating subtotals and totals from a dictionary

Tags: swift

Is there a better way to write this code, using Swift? I am using a nested for loop and I could not think of a better way to write this code. I am just a beginner trying to figure this out.

```
var products = [
    ["product": "soap", "price": 3.50],
    ["product": "cereal", "price": 2.56],
    ["product": "soup", "price": 3.25]
]

var shoppingCart = ["soap", "cereal"]


var count = 0
var subTotal = 0.0
for product in products {
    for cartItem in shoppingCart.enumerate() {
        if cartItem.element == products[count]["product"] {
            print(cartItem.element)
            if count <= products.count {
                count += 1
                var cost = products[count]["price"]! as! Double
                subTotal += cost
            }
        }
    }
}
let totalCost = subTotal * 1.086
print("The total cost of your shopping cart $\(totalCost).")
```

Comment: Your data structure in inappropriate – you should most likely be using an array of `Product` structs, or a dictionary mapping some kind of product ID (names are fine if they're unique) to a `Product` struct (or just the price if that's the only property). A dictionary would be good in this case for fast lookup.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using dictionaries?

Answer (score 2):

If you make your products into a `dictionary` that maps product name to price, then you can use `reduce` to add up the values:

```
var products = [
    "soap": 3.50,
    "cereal": 2.56,
    "soup": 3.25
]

var shoppingCart = ["soap", "cereal"]

let totalCost = 1.086 * shoppingCart.reduce(0.0, combine: { $0 + (products[$1] ?? 0) })
```

Notes:

1. Reduce starts with an initial value `0.0` and adds the value of each of the products as it finds them.  `$0` is the running total, and `$1` holds each of the values in the shopping cart in turn.
2. If you have a product in your cart that doesn't have a listed price, then the dictionary look up will return `nil`.  The *nil coalescing operator* `??` is used here to safely unwrap the value returned from the dictionary and use a default price of `0` if the product isn't found.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your dictionaries structure is not very good for the result you want to achieve. Since you didn't wrote that you must use dictionaries, I have used native Swift classes and structures to achieve the result you need. It's much easier to test, maintain and use in the long run.

First define `Product` class:

```
class Product {
    let name: String
    let price: Double

    init(name: String, price: Double) {
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
}
```

Now create instances of your product:

```
let soap = Product(name: "Soap", price: 3.5)
let cereal = Product(name: "Cereal", price: 2.56)
let soup = Product(name: "Soup", price: 3.25)
```

And the shopping cart (two soaps and one cereal package):

```
var shoppingCart = [soap, soap, cereal]
```

You would get a count by running this:

```
let count = shoppingCart.count // returns 3
```

And the subtotal with this:

```
var subTotal = shoppingCart.reduce(0.0, combine: {$0 + $1.price})
// Would return 9.56
```

Note that I'm using `reduce` functional method on array, to make the computation short as possible, but you could also loop through shopping cart and get the same result.